# How to get last modified text files by date from remote FTP location

Tags: php, ftp

I am stuck on atomization of an process to download last modified text files on date wise or today. Here is my code.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '-rt .');
reset($contents);

function is_txt($file) {
    return preg_match('/.*\.txt/', $file) > 0;
}

$filtered = array_filter($contents, is_txt);

// download all files in downloaded directory
while (list($key, $value) = each($filtered )) {

    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $dir.'\\downloaded\\'.$value, $value, FTP_BINARY))   {
        echo "Successfully written to $value\n";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem\n";
    }
}
```

I got success in getting text files, but not selecting the last modified files, `filemtime` is not helping me nor curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PHP 7.2, you can use [`ftp_mlsd` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mlsd.php) to retrieve list of files including their timestamps. Check the `"modify"` entry. You can then easily identify the latest file.

---

With older versions of PHP, you will need to use the [`ftp_mdtm` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mdtm.php) to retrieve the modification time of files.

But you have to call it individually for every file, what is pretty inefficient. See [Downloading only new images from FTP server in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43045253/850848).

You can also try an implementation of the `MLSD` in user comments of the `ftp_rawlist` command:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php#101071

First check if your FTP server supports `MLSD` before taking this approach, as not all FTP servers do (particularly [IIS and vsftpd don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49528887/850848)).

---

The only other way is to use the [`ftp_rawlist` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php). But its returns a `ls`-like line for every file with no pre-defined format. If you connect to one specific server, you can use it; and hard-code the parsing based on the specifics of the server. But it's not reliable, if you need to connect to an arbitrary server.

Typical listing on a *nix server is like:

```
drwxr-x---   3 vincent  vincent      4096 Jul 12 12:16 public_ftp
drwxr-x---  15 vincent  vincent      4096 Nov  3 21:31 public_html
-rwxrwxrwx   1 vincent  vincent        11 Jul 12 12:16 file.txt
```

For some basic code, see [PHP FTP recursive directory listing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36310247/850848) – That that does not include the timestamp parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Martin With your help i was able to solve above problem

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '-rt .');
reset($contents);

function is_txt($file) {
 return preg_match('/.*\.txt/', $file) > 0;
}

$filtered = array_filter($contents, is_txt);
$array = array();
//download all files in downloaded directory
while (list($key, $value) = each($filtered )) {
    $buff = ftp_mdtm($conn_id, $value);

    if ($buff != -1) {
        array_push($array,date("F d Y", $buff)); 
    } 


}
$lmdate = array_pop($array);

$key="";
$value="";
reset($filtered);
while (list($key, $value) = each($filtered )) 
 {

    $buff1 = ftp_mdtm($conn_id, $value);
    $cdate=date("F d Y", $buff1);

    if (($buff1 != -1) and ($cdate == $lmdate)){

        if (ftp_get($conn_id, $dir.'\\downloaded\\'.$value, $value, FTP_BINARY)) {

            echo "Successfully written to $value\n";
            } else {
            echo "There was a problem\n";
        }
    } 

}
```