# PHP ftp_nlist timestamp

Tags: php, ftp

I was wondering if it is possible to add timestamp of the file creation/update when using ftp_nlist().

My code right now:

```
function ftp_get_recursive_paths($conn, $path, $max_level = 0){
    $files = array();
    if($max_level < 0) return $files;
    if($path !== '/' && $path[strlen($path) - 1] !== '/') $path .= '/';
    $files_list = ftp_nlist($conn, $path);

    foreach($files_list as $f){
        if($f !== '.' && $f !== '..' && $f !== $path){
            if(strpos($f, '.') === FALSE){
                $files[$f] = ftp_get_recursive_paths($conn, $f, $max_level-1);
            }else{
                $files[] = basename($f);
            }    
        }
    }

    return $files;
}
```

And output:

```
(
    [/folder1] => (
            [0] => file.php
            [1] => file2.php
        )

    [/folder2] => (
            [/folder2/2] => (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What does it mean "add timestamp"? Do you want to retrieve timestamps of the listed files?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yep, add timestamp of the listed files. Like: file1.php - 10-19-2016...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last modified text files by date from remote FTP location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147534/how-to-get-last-modified-text-files-by-date-from-remote-ftp-location)

Comment: you can use `ftp_rawlist` to get more detailed list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
function ftp_get_recursive_paths($conn, $path, $max_level = 0){
    $files = array();
    if($max_level < 0) return $files;
    if($path !== '/' && $path[strlen($path) - 1] !== '/') $path .= '/';
    $files_list = ftp_nlist($conn, $path);

    foreach($files_list as $f){
        if($f !== '.' && $f !== '..' && $f !== $path){
            if(strpos($f, '.') === FALSE){
                $files[$f] = ftp_get_recursive_paths($conn, $f, $max_level-1);
            }else{
                $mdate = ftp_mdtm($conn, $f);
                $files[] = basename($f) . " - " . date("m-d-Y H:i:s.", $mdate);
            }    
        }
    }

    return $files;
}
```