# Get File from FTP server only for current date via FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to get a file from FTP with the last modified date as today. This works perfectly if I know the file name.

In my FTP server, the file name is dynamic. I only know the file extension which .csv and has one CSV file with many other different files.

how do I get only the .csv file which has the last modified date as the current date? Once I get it I will download that file from FTP.

This is what I tried and works fine ONLY if I know the file name.

```
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "ftp server details";
$ftp_username = 'ftp user';
$ftp_userpass = 'ftp pass';
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

//hard coded file name. I want to get only .csv file (It is just one file)
$file = "/MYDATA/2020_10_27_15_00.csv";

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$currenttime = date( 'F d Y', strtotime( 'now' ) );

$lastchanged = ftp_mdtm($ftp_conn, $file);
if ($lastchanged != -1)
{
 
  $lastmodifieddate = date("F d Y", $lastchanged);
   
  if (strcmp($currenttime, $lastmodifieddate) == 0)
  {
      echo "$file was last modified on : " . date("F d Y", $lastchanged);
      //download the file
  }
  else
  {
      echo "No file for current date";
      //nothing to download
  }
  
}
else
{
  echo "Could not get last modified";
}

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);


?>
```

How to get filename only for .csv extension with last modified date as the current date and download the file from FTP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the files and loop them, get the modified date of each one and compare to today's date (not tested):

```
$files = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, "/MYDATA/*.csv");
$today = date("Ymd");

foreach($files as $file) {
    $mtime = date("Ymd", ftp_mdtm($ftp_conn, $file));

    if($mtime == $today) {
        $found = $file;
        break;  // if there is only one or you only want one
    }
}

if(isset($found)) {
    echo "$found is today's date $today!";
    // download $found
} else {
    echo "No file found for today's date $today!";
}
```

If there could be multiple files with today's date then assign to an array and do something else with them:

```
if($mtime == $today) {
    $found[] = $file;
}
```

**NOTE**: This solution will be slow especially with many files.  You may look at [ftp_rawlist](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) or issue a `ls` or similar command with sorting using [ftp_raw](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-raw.php) and then parse out the date.

Thanks to [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl)'s comment, you might be able to do something like this, getting the file information into an multidimensional array and checking that:

```
$files = ftp_mlsd($conn_id, "/MYDATA/*.csv");
$today = date("Ymd");

$found = array_filter($files, function($v) use($today) {
                                  return substr($v["modify"], 0, 8) == $today;
                              });
```

Then you can get the name(s):

```
$found = array_column($found, "name");
```

If [ftp_mlsd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mlsd.php) doesn't accept wildcards, then you'll need to add checking the `$v["name"]` for `.csv` extension to the filter code.

Comment: While this indeed works, it's can be quite inefficient to use `ftp_mdtm` for each file. For alternatives, see [How to get last modified text files by date from remote FTP location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29147534/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  Thanks, added a note and something better to look at.

Comment: Got it but ftp_mlsd is always empty.

Comment: Haven’t tested it might not take wildcards *.csv do a `print_r(ftp_mlsd($conn_id, "/MYDATA/));` to see if that works.

Comment: Nothing is comning up. It is empty

Comment: Also just figured out if I use foreach($files as $file) I am getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Warning.  How to get rid of that?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: What happens to yesterday's code when there is multiple *.csv with today's date? Will it take latest file?